# Displaying a number of years in a for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop

Im having a hard time displaying a number of years in my code using a for loop, i want to iterate through and print the years the user input and the number next to it.

```
case 1:
    cout << "Enter the number of credit hours for this semester: ";
    cin >> credHours;
    cout << "Enter the number of years to display (excluding year 1): ";
    cin >> yrs;

    tuition = (credHours * LEVEL0);

    for (int i = 1; i < yrs; i++) {
        cout << "Year: " << i << " " << tuition << endl;
        tuition = (tuition * INCREASE) + tuition;
        cout << "Year: " << i + 1 << " " << tuition << endl;
        


        break;
    }
    break;
```

Comment: Show the output you are getting with this program. Share the expected output. Also, what is `LEVEL0` and `INCREASE`?

Comment: @H.S. Its a tuition calculator and the increase is how much its going up by in the next years and the level is just the base tuition cost per credit hour, i got it fixed though.

Comment: After the first 3 statements are encountered, a `break` is encountered.  The execution then leaves the `for` loop because that's what the `break` does.  If you want to keep the `break` in the loop, put some kind of condition around it.  Otherwise, get rid of the loop; since the code is only executed once (in the loop), there is no need for a loop.

Answer (score 2):

There is a break in your for loop, which will 'jump out'. Try this:

```
case 1:
cout << "Enter the number of credit hours for this semester: ";
cin >> credHours;
cout << "Enter the number of years to display (excluding year 1): ";
cin >> yrs;

tuition = (credHours * LEVEL0);

for (int i = 1; i < yrs; i++) {
    cout << "Year: " << i << " " << tuition << endl;
    tuition = (tuition * INCREASE) + tuition;
    cout << "Year: " << i + 1 << " " << tuition << endl;
    // Don't break;
}
break;
```